# Shuffle Using SoX?

Tags: music, sox, music-player

Is there anyway to shuffle songs using `play` on a folder using `SoX`?

`play ~/Music/*/**`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sort -R` to reorder the file list into "random" order. The command could be the following:

```
find ~/Music -type f | sort -R | xargs -I + play +
```

Here `find ~/Music -type f` results in a list of of all files in the `Music` subtree, recursively. The resulting pathname list is then "sorted" into a random order by `sort -R`, and passed as arguments to successive `play` invocations with some few/many pathnames at a time. Note the use of `+` as "replace string", to invoke individual `play` for each music file.

(Edit: as per Warren's comment below, I've now removed the useless but harmless single quotes for the second `+`.)

Comment: The `'+'` syntax doesn't do what you think it does. The shell will remove the quotes before passing the `+` to `xargs`. The reason it works anyway is that you're using `-I` which — in addition to setting a replacement string — also changes the input delimiter to newline. You could use `-d '\n'` to get the same effect here, since you don't need a custom command insertion point in this case. (That is, the default to tack the argument on to the end of the command is just what you want.)

Comment: Beware that `sort -R` is nonstandard. If your system doesn't have it, it may have [`rl`](https://arthurdejong.org/rl/) or [`shuf`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/shuf) instead, which do the same thing.